# Nginx root not working as I expected

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to achieve the following:

The root of my domain `http://www.paulix.local/` should server the file located at `/var/www/html/main/webroot/index.php`

The url `http://www.paulix.local/malibu`should serve the file located at `/var/www/domain/malibu/webroot/index.php`

The rewrite I am trying to achieve (url => script) :

- / => /var/www/html/main/webroot/index.php
- /path/whatever => /var/www/html/main/webroot/index.php?/path/whatever
- /malibu => /var/www/domain/malibu/webroot/index.php
- /malibu/path/whatever => /var/www/domain/malibu/webroot/index.php?/path/whatever

This is my current config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    rewrite_log on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/paulix-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/paulix-errors.log notice;

    server_name www.paulix.local;
    root /var/www/html/main/webroot;
    index index.php;

    # location 1
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # location 2
    location ~ /malibu {
        root /var/www/domain/malibu/webroot;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        # location 3
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 200 "Malibu is $document_root$fastcgi_script_name";
        }
    }

    # location 4
    location ~ \.php$ {
            return 200 "Global $document_root$fastcgi_script_name";
    }
}
```

If I hit the url `http://www.paulix.local`, it hits location 4 and I get the following output: `Global /var/www/html/main/webroot/index.php` which is what I'm expecting.

PROBLEMS

If I hit the url `http://www.paulix.local/malibu` it also hits location 4 with the same output as above, but I was expecting it to hit location 3, the expected output being: `Malibu is /var/www/domain/malibu/webroot/index.php`

Lastly, hitting `http://www.paulix.local/malibu/index.php` hits location 3, but not with the expected output. It outputs `Malibu is /var/www/domain/malibu/webroot/malibu/index.php` when I'd like it to be `/var/www/domain/malibu/webroot/index.php`

Comment: Note that the order of location stanzas is important. Try placing the malibu one as the first one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:** The problem is due to a [bug in Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426812/nginx-try-files-alias-directives)

One solution is the one below, or even better [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642689/234594)

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
rewrite_log on;
access_log /var/log/nginx/paulix-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/paulix-errors.log notice;


server_name www.paulix.test;
root /var/www/html;

location / {
    root /var/www/html/main;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # prevent recursion
    if ($request_uri ~ /webroot/index.php) {
        break;
    }

    #rewrite ^/$ / permanent; # do not uncomment, or face infinite rewrite
    rewrite ^/webroot/(.*) /webroot/index.php last;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /webroot/$1 last;

        location ~ index\.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}

location /malibu {
        root /var/www/domain;

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # prevent recursion
    if ($request_uri ~ /webroot/index.php) {
        break;
    }

    rewrite ^/malibu$ /malibu/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/malibu/webroot/(.*) /malibu/webroot/index.php last;
    rewrite ^/malibu/(.*)$ /malibu/webroot/$1 last;

        location ~ index\.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Based on your needs, use `location /malibu {` or `location ^~ /malibu {`instead of `location ~ /malibu {`.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks) you can read an understandable overview how Nginx deals with location-blocks.

edit: Sorry, I haven't seen your last edit as I wrote my answer. I think it is `alias` you are searching for. Just replace `root` in location 2 with `alias` and the output should be fine. ([Source](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and the link, but it doesn't change anything